# How to cancel snapshot operation in softlayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For the cancel operation for snapshot space, i'm trying to call cancellation request.
it returns error when we try it.

Billing item \"20 GB Storage Space\" cannot be canceled via this service. Please create a cancellation ticket

```
Item cancelItem = new cancellation.request.Item(); 
cancelItem.setBillingItemId(item.getId());
cancelItem.setImmediateCancellationFlag(true);
snapshot.getItems().add(cancelItem);
cancelService.createObject(snapshot);
```

How can I cancel billing item for snapshot space ?

If you provide a sample java code or API guide, it will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to cancel the storage space snapshot, well the SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject method works fine for that. It seems to me you are using the wrong billing Item, you need to make sure that the billig item is for "snapshot space", for that you need to pick out the billing item whose "description" contains "(Snapshot Space)" or whose "categoryCode" says "storage_snapshot_space".

This objectMask will help you to list the billing items:

```
mask[billingItem[children]]
```

Here an example using REST:

```
    GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$StorageID/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[children]]

Note: Replace $StorageID, you need to look up the billing item in the children
```

but if you only want to cancel the "storage space" that is not possible, you have to cancel the whole storage device.

Regards